# What are good strategies for Master Quest rule "Don't Get Hit!" missions?

Tags: hyrule-warriors

In Hyrule Warriors, "Don't get hit!" missions are full fledged missions in which your character dies in 2 hits (1 brings to 1/4 heart, another finishes you) - also not to be confused with the shorter "All attacks are devastating!" missions, as in those, the monsters also die in one hit.

I've tried a multitude of different characters and strategies, and everything falls apart against harder captains and generals (specially Wizzro and his magic-spamming). I'm seeing no other solution than grind a lot to the point of killing stuff extremely fast, but then I would be missing on a lot of rewards that require this sort of mission finished (such as Cia's level 2 weapon).

Is there an easier or cheesy way to finish this kind of mission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are some of the worst missions, and the best solution I have found is to use the potion mixture which grants you unlimited powered up items. Simply spam the bomb for regular enemies, and the arrow to stun captains/named monsters. This requires you've leveled up the potion maker by collecting enough skulltula tokens, and that you have enough materials to burn.

Comment: That's actually a pretty good idea. Do you know if we lose the effects of a potion if we choose to restart a mission? I would very much like to get A on this kind of mission on my first try.

Comment: As far as I know, you keep the effects of a potion until you complete or possibly abort a mission. I'm confident I have restarted a mission and kept the buff.